# Expected to return a value in arrow function - useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have the below useEffect, but in my es-lint it shows as a warning in return i am not returning anything.

Is there a better way to achieve this or do i need to `return null`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!data && !data.length) return;
    data.map((datumn, index) => {
      setData(
        `name_${datumn.id}_${index}`,
        checkValue(
          datumn.isValid,
          datumn.dob
        )
      );
    });
  }, [data]);
```

Comment: You need to return something from your `.map` call. `.map` is used to build a new array. If you just wanted to do something for each item, then the proper way is using `.forEach`. As a side note, it's better to build the whole array using `.map`, then set the state once at the end after using the new array. Setting state in a loop can cause many re-renders and degrade performance

Comment: Got it i was confused that if condition return was the issue, thanks for correcting at @Jayce444. Using forEach

Comment: @JosephD. Nope its not set a state, naming was added in a way like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> warning in return i am not returning anything.

The warning means the callback function used in `.map()` should return something.

```
// no implicit return
(datumn, index) => {...}
```

If you don't want to return something, use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and rather use an implicit return in the callback function.

```
data.forEach((datumn, index) => ( // implicit return
  setData(
    `name_${datumn.id}_${index}`,
    checkValue(datumn.isValid, datumn.dob)
  )
));
```